# Visual Studio Regex with negation not working

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, regex-negation

I'm trying to do a Regex for Visual Studio search that finds me all the calls to the methods of a certain class that don't use callback (the class is a proxy, and I want to find the synchronous calls).

I want to find this kind of calls:

```
jc.GetStuff (data1, data2, data3);
```

But not this:

```
jc.GetStuff (data1, data2, data3, GetStuffCallback);
```

So I'm trying with this:

```
~(<jc>..*<(>.*<Callback>.*<)>)<jc>..*<(>.*<)>
```

and, not knowing if I should escape those parenthesis:

```
~(<jc>..*<\(>.*<Callback>.*<\)>)<jc>..*<\(>.*<\)>
```

I can't figure why this isn't working... what am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what all of the angle brackets are in your expression, but how about something like this?

```
jc\..+\((?!.*Callback.*).*\);
```

```
jc                   literal string jc
\.                   full stop (escaped)
.*                   any character 1 or more times
\(                   opening bracket (escaped)
(?!.*Callback.*)     negative lookahead for callback
.*                   any character 0 or more times
\(                   closing bracket (escaped)
;                    literal string ;
```